# sql point system

Tags: php, sql

I am currently making a small site with a point system, unfortunately when I click on my button 
 to make the query, no error but the point is not added to the database, here is my code :

Point.php

```
<div class="posttest">
  <form action="traitement/point.php" method="get">
   <p>
    <input type="submit" name="nbVoteP"/><br>
  </p>
 </form>
</div>
```

and the processing page:

```
<?php
require('connexion.php');
$reponse = $bdd->query("UPDATE `image` SET `nbVoteP` = '+1' WHERE ` 
image`.`id` = 1");
header('Location: ../point.php');
?>
```

Thank you for your answer

Comment: `UPDATE image SET nbVoteP = nbVoteP + 1 WHERE id = 1`

Comment: Oh boy, I don't even know where to behin.. can you provide your connexion.php also

Comment: If you want to increment use: `SET nbVoteP = nbVoteP+1` otherwise you only ever just set positive 1.

Comment: Is there really a new line between the opening backtick and "image"?